# Json to vb.net string (Newtonsoft.Json)

Tags: json, vb.net

hi i have this json string

```
[ { "desc" : "Unlike other foxes that roamed the woods of southern Ionia, Ahri had always felt a strange connection to the magical world around her; a connection that was somehow incomplete. Deep inside, she felt the skin she had been born into was an ill fit for her and dreamt of one day...",
    "id" : 103,
    "name" : "Ahri",
    "tags" : [ "assassin",
        "mage",
        "ranged"
      ]
  },
  { "desc" : "There exists an ancient order originating in the Ionian Isles dedicated to the preservation of balance. Order, chaos, light, darkness -- all things must exist in perfect harmony for such is the way of the universe. This order is known as the Kinkou and it employs a triumvirate...",
    "id" : 84,
    "name" : "Akali",
    "tags" : [ "assassin",
        "melee",
        "stealth"
      ]
  },
  { "desc" : "As the mightiest warrior to ever emerge from the Minotaur tribes of the Great Barrier, Alistar defended his tribe from Valoran's many dangers; that is, until the coming of the Noxian army. Alistar was lured from his village by the machinations of Keiran Darkwill, General Boram...",
    "id" : 12,
    "name" : "Alistar",
    "tags" : [ "tank",
        "pusher",
        "melee"
      ]
  }
```

i want to get the name property from the id property 
like i want to convert the id 103 to champion and the end result will give me "Ahri"
this is my code so far

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim json As JsonConverter
            Dim ent As champion = TryCast(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of champion)(json), champion)
            MsgBox(ent.name)
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class champion
        Public Property desc As String

        Public Property id As Integer

        Public Property name As String

        Public Property tags As List(Of tags)
    End Class
    Public Class tags
        Public Property type As Array
```

original json : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nagash/1688617/raw/2a98e542aaabfc03f6db4328bd4dc98fc263df5a/lol-champions.json

But it gets this error

An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'json_test.champion' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: that is an invalid JSON string - missing a closing `]`.  Otherwise, *but it didnt work* is not very helpful.  Where did it come from?  Did you create it?  When fixed, it should deserialize to a List(of Champion) very nicely (or array, if you must)

Comment: hi i have changed the coed but it still gets an error , here is the original one mine might be missing because i only a snippet because it is very long https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nagash/1688617/raw/2a98e542aaabfc03f6db4328bd4dc98fc263df5a/lol-champions.json

Comment: you are going to have to be more specific "it still gets an error" does tell me anything. The same error? The link doesnt contain 1 item, it contains 91, so as I said, *it deserializes to a List(of Champion) very nicely*.  Please update your post with the code you have and the current error.

Comment: the post does contain the new error :
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'json_test.champion' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.